# JAVASCRIPT WEB UI: Handle new temporary elements before server returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, web

I'm looking to create a snappy web-UI where a user can add a row below the currently active row in a grid of elements just by pressing enter. The user could in theory press enter several times to create multiple new rows below. Every row contains an input field. Each row represents a record in my database.

Now I need to handle the fact that one or more elements is added instantly to the ui, but the id of every corresponding record is set server side later. Once we have the id, the user may already have entered something in the ui-row.

I'm thinking that one solution would be to add a virtual "ui-id" -field to be created on the fly at UI runtime. The UI-ID would not be persisted in the database but only used for ui-reference. Every row in the ui, new and old, would get a "ui-id". As soon as the server returns the id, it would be attached to the new row.

**What would be another good way of handling temporary new rows that yet haven't recieved an id from the server?**

Waiting for the server before adding the row in the UI would not be an alternative.

Comment: Your question seems not to be asked here. You are asking about a whole project flow. anyway why can't you try jquery Grid / http://handsontable.com/

Comment: The intent of the question is not to find a framework that handles a grid. It is to solve a problem that i imagine could surface in various situations where asynchronious requests puts ui and server temporarily out of sync. Thank you for helping to clarify the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can go for jQuery Grid or handsontable.
Try :

> http://paramquery.com/demos

You have option to save data too with handsontable. It is an exel like UI. Which has all the features you discussed here.
Please go through thourougly :

> http://docs.handsontable.com 
>   http://docs.handsontable.com/0.19.0/tutorial-load-and-save.html